# jQuery Crossslide alternative? Photo moving into a direction

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am developing a website for a church. As you can imagine, a church is quite tall in height. If you place a photo of that building into a horizontal banner of a size of let's say 700x200 there's no way you will see much of the building in the photo.

I can't really change much of the design anymore so I searched around and found Crossslide:

http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

If you scroll down to the 2nd example (Slide and cross-fade) you will see that one image is shown and it goes from top to bottom so to speak. I tried implementing this script but failed and gave up after many, many hours. Another issue is that the creater of that plugin doesn't give any more support. So now I am hoping if you guys/girls have alternative idea's / plugin's.

We do not want to use Flash though. So jQuery would be the best solution. Does anyone know a nice plugin that does that CrossSlide did in the 2nd example?

Thank you.

Comment: Why didn't that script work? Did you include it in the page and check that the browser downloaded and parsed the script? Did you follow the documentation correctly and bind the slider to your container with images in them?

Comment: Yes. I did get the first example working fine, but I needed the second example. On the bottom of the page he placed the function for the 2nd example and it did not work. No image showed up while I did not change the path. Like I said, it did work on the first example. It's kind of strange,  because there isn't much difference between the two scripts. Firefox also showed an error "crossSlide: impossible animation:either picture 1 is too small or div is too large or fade is too long" which all wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I'm guessing you are trying it with just 1 image.

I just got done messing with this myself and had that same issue, added another module even with the same image and it works perfectly fine.

Example:

```
var $image = 'images/our_practice_banner.jpg'

$('#banner').crossSlide({
  loop: 1,
  fade: 1
}, [
  {
    src:  $image,
    from: 'top right 1.5x',
    to:   'center center 1x',
    time: 4
  },{
    src:  $image,
    from: 'center center 1x',
    to:   'center center 1x',
    time: 4
  }
]);
```